# Diagram: I wanna change the color of a cell depending on the value from coordinate point

Tags: diagrams, metadata

Hello I am from Germany sorry for my English.

Here is my Question:

I want to create a diagram. I have a table with certain points. Every point has a specific value. Only one point can be in a cell. I want to fill this cell (where the point is) with color depending on the high of the value from this point.
Here is an example Picture:
[image]

Attention here is an example. Only the size and color of the point are changing not the cell/fill color where the point is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{filled circle}{%
  \pgfpathellipse
    {\pgfpointorigin}%
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0sp}}%
    {\pgfqpoint{0sp}{\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfusepathqfill% mark=* uses \pgfusepathqfillstroke instead
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
     A B C
     1 1.5 10
     2 2 40 
     3. 4.2 2000 
     1.6 4.5 400 
}\datentabelle

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
colorbar,
grid=both,
xmin=0, xmax=9,
ymin=0, ymax=9,
legend entries={$\tau$},
title=Diagramm
]

\addplot[
  scatter,
  only marks,
  scatter src=explicit,
  mark=filled circle,
  mark options={draw=none},
  scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={%
    /tikz/mark size={.8pt+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/550},
  },
]
  table[meta expr=abs(\thisrow{C})] {\datentabelle};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In German:
Bei meinem neuen Diagramm habe ich pro Feld/Zelle nur einen Punkt (Koordinaten-Punkt). Dieser Koordinatenpunkt besitzt einen Wert (Spalte C in meinem Table). Je nach Höhe des Wertes soll das jeweilige Feld (Zelle) wo der Punkt liegt mit einer Farbe eingefärbt werden. Bei meinem Beispiel ändert sich leider nur die Farbe und Größe des Punktes in Abhängigkeit von der Höhe des Wertes nicht jedoch die Färbung der jeweiligen Zelle. Ziel wäre nur die Färbung der jeweiligen Zelle.

Achtung: Sollte der Punkt auf einer Ecke wie hier im Beispiel Punkt 2 (x=2/y=2) liegen, sollte das nächst größere Feld/Zelle angetriggert werden oder Punkt (1.5/2) siehe Screenshot: